# ps -o not working in HP-UX ia64 11.26 machine

Tags: unix, ps, hp-ux

```
ps -o etime,pid,tty,comm -u "$user" | while read etime  pid tty comm
```

This is the code snippet of my script and here ps -o command not applicale in HP unix.But it is available in solaris and aix.

So,for getting this is there any other options available?

Answer (score 0):

ps -o should work, but you need to set an environment variable to specify the UNIX standard.  According to my notes, you should set the following

```
11.23 - UNIX95
11.31 - UNIX_STD=2003
```

But just setting UNIX95 seems to work on either, so my notes may be wrong.  One or the other will probably work for 11.26 though.  Check the man page for ps, it should have some more info.